# Unable to properly understand vprintf() in PHP

Tags: php, string, printf

I am unable to understand the following code:

```
<?php
   $number = 123;
   vprintf("With 2 decimals: %1\$.2f
   <br>With no decimals: %1\$u",array($number));
?>
```

Browser output:

```
With 2 decimals: 123.00 
With no decimals: 123
```

But here there is only one element in array, whereas it has to be two arguments.

Also what is the meaning of `%1\$`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's a way to specify which parameter you want to use. `%1$s` indicates the first parameter, `%2$s` the second, etc. It's a way of re-using a single parameter so you don't have to supply the same value multiple times in the function call:

```
$one = 'one';
$two = 'two';

printf('%s', $one); // 'one'
printf('%1$s', $one); // 'one'
printf('%s %s', $one, $two); // 'one two'
printf('%1$s %2$s', $one, $two); // 'one two'
printf('%2$s %1$s', $one, $two); // 'two one'

printf('%1$s %2$s %1$s', $one, $two); // 'one two one'
```

In your code, it's escaped with a `\` because your format is in double quotes, which would try to parse a variable `$.2f` or `$u` (which don't exist) if the dollar sign is not escaped.

Comment: Using double quotes in printf is pointless and leads to issues like this, the very reason it is used to move the variables out of the string.

Comment: It's a common developer preference though, especially among developers that came from strongly typed languages where double quotes are for strings and single quotes for chars.